# Could someone please provide a walkthrough on how to setup a self signing ssl certificate on cloud 9?

Tags: python, ssl, cloud9-ide

I am migrating my personal hobby python web application from 127.0.0.1 to cloud 9 lately, but found myself completely new to the idea of setting up ssl certificate. I did some online research on openssl and its python wrapper but still couldn't find any definitive guide on how to set it up in practice, specifically for the cloud 9 IDE platform.

Could someone please give a walkthough, or point out some references link here? Thanks.

By the way, I'm using cherrypy for the python server.

EDIT: specifically, I have the following questions:

- is it requred to run openssl from the server(in my case, cloud9 bash), or I can run openssl from my local laptop then upload the generated key and cert?
- does it make any sense to use passphrase to protect the key? I don't see any point here, correct me if I'm wrong please
- how to install it to cloud9?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 runs your app behind an https proxy, so you need to just use http, since cloud9 proxy won't accept your self signed certificate.

Comment: Cloud9 runs behind https, but it demands your app to serve ssl/tls content, or otherwise it will block all the requests. So just using http won't work here. Have you tried that before yourself?

Comment: no, cloud9 doesn't require serving ssl, serving http on right port and ip is enough

Comment: @a user I'm afraid your opinion is not working in my case, I just tried and all my clicked requested were blocked by chrome, saying it demands a ssl connection.